# Vue v-for click not show correcly element

Tags: vue.js, render, v-for

for` to show data from database:

```
<div v-for="item in resourceList" :key="item.id">
    <input :id="roomData.id" type="checkbox" @click="saveCheckbox">
    <label :for="roomData.id">{{ item.question }}</label>

        //calendar
        <span v-if="active">
            <datepicker v-model="date"></datepicker>
        </span>
        <span v-else id="disableCalendar">Not show calendar</span>
</div>
```

I have problem with function click. For example on page `v-for` show 10 elements. In each element there will be a button to click `@click="saveCheckbox"`.

Function in methods:

```
saveCheckbox(e){            
    if(e.target.checked) {
        this.active = true;
    } else {
        this.active = false;
    }
}
```

In data I have:

```
active = false;
```

Now when user click in for example first element button, the calendar will appear in EACH element.
How I can show calendar ONLY in element which user clicked ?

Comment: what is the connection between this.active = true with datepicker?

Comment: @ChristhoferNatalius No connection between this.active and datapicker. I used `v-if="active"` to show datapicker when `this.active` in `true` or show text "Not show calendar" when `this.active` in `false`.

Comment: Ah, I see your problem. Vucko's solution should work. You need array of active, and saveCheckbox should update one of the element inside active array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the value for each item in the loop. With `this.active = true` you have only one state which you use for every item in the loop.

Example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    isActive: [false, false, false, false]
  },
  methods: {
    toggleActive(index) {
      this.$set(this.isActive, index, !this.isActive[index])
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(active, index) in isActive" :key="index">
    {{ active }} {{ index }}
    <button type="button" @click="toggleActive(index)">Toggle</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tkanks, for your answer, but I have a question: How I can create `isActive` (in data) if I don't know how many element user added ?

Comment: @michal add the property in your `resourceList ` array.

Answer (score 2):

The `active` variable is shared for each item in your resourceList, you need to create active identifier for each item in your list, one way to do it is to have `active` property of item of resourceList. Assuming you have active property in each item of resourceList, you can do the following.

```
<div v-for="item in resourceList" :key="item.id">
    <input :id="roomData.id" type="checkbox" @click="saveCheckbox(item)">
    <label :for="roomData.id">{{ item.question }}</label>

        //calendar
        <span v-if="active">
            <datepicker v-model="date"></datepicker>
        </span>
        <span v-else id="disableCalendar">Not show calendar</span>
</div>
```

And the saveCheckbox method

```
saveCheckbox(item){            
   item.active = !item.active
}
```